# Com Interop in .netcore (using vb6 com dll)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I cannot load a vb6 style com dll at all. I get a "class not registered" error even though it is. So a vb6 com dll is not supported at all in .net core? Has anyone else tried this?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var r = Ole32Methods.CoInitialize(new IntPtr(0));

    const uint CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER = 1;
    Guid clsid = new Guid("C31CBF72-92C6-4A47-A4C4-935706C26D34");

    // GUID of the required interface
    Guid IID_IUnknown = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");

    object instance = null;

    uint hResult = Ole32Methods.CoCreateInstance(ref clsid, null,
                   CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ref IID_IUnknown, out instance);

    _ICommonUI sidCUI = instance as _ICommonUI;

    sidCUI.Show(1, null);
}
```

Comment: .NETCore likes 64-bit code, VB6 components don't.  Very little point in targeting .NETCore, that VB6 component can only ever run on a machine that also has the full framework version.

Comment: Thanks for the response Hans. Yes the .net core team has indicated to me that .net core is 64-bit only at this time...

Comment: oops my comment is a little off... They only support x64 but x86 is available! see https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#core